# Can't use Ion Auth's login method in another controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I added controllers/Site.php , views/site/login.php to my project but when I submit login form i always get */application/views/site/login#
Do anyone knows why? whats the problem?

here is my Site.php :

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Site extends MY_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('ion_auth');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('string');

    $this->load->database();

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters($this->config->item('error_start_delimiter', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('error_end_delimiter', 'ion_auth'));

    $this->lang->load('auth');
    $this->load->helper('language');

    $this->data['pageTitle'] = $this->lang->line('login_page_title');
}

//redirect if needed, otherwise display the user list
function index() {
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        //redirect them to the login page
        redirect('site/login', 'refresh');
    } else if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin()) { //remove this elseif if you want to enable this for non-admins
        //redirect them to the home page because they must be an administrator to view this
        return show_error('You must be an administrator to view this page.');
    }
}

//log the user in
function login() {

    $this->data['title'] = "Login";

    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('identity', 'Identity', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
        //check to see if the user is logging in
        //check for "remember me"
        $remember = (bool) $this->input->post('remember');

        if ($this->ion_auth->login($this->input->post('identity'), $this->input->post('password'), $remember)) {
            //if the login is successful
            //redirect them back to the home page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->messages());
            redirect('/', 'refresh');
        } else {
            //if the login was un-successful
            //redirect them back to the login page
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->ion_auth->errors());
            redirect('site/login', 'refresh'); //use redirects instead of loading views for compatibility with MY_Controller libraries
        }
    }

        $this->_render_page('site/login', $this->data);
}
}
```

And here is my simple login.php :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form role="form" action="#" method="post">

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="email" id="identity" name="identity" placeholder="Your email address" value="admin@mail.com">
    </div>

    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Your password" value="password">
    </div>

    <div class="checkbox-group">
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="remember" name="remember" data-toggle="checkbox">
        <label for="remember">Remember Me</label>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Log me in</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Form action should be `action="<?php echo base_url('site/login'); ?>"`

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function base_url()

Comment: Strange. It is error if url helper is not available/loaded. Your code points that url helper is loaded. Check if issue occures because it is loaded twice (i.e. both in autoload file and in controller). If so, autoload it in `APPPATH . 'config/autoload.php'` only.

Comment: this login page is in "site" folder and "auth" folder is secured by .htaccess cuz of it every time when i point auth/login in form action it says "You don't have permission to access */application/view/auth/login on this server." i think maybe its because of security reasons (and btw project is really big and bought it from http://themeforest.net/item/allec-bootstrapless-template-with-site-builder/8986248 cuz of it its really hard to deal with it)

Comment: .htaccess file in /application/ folder : `Deny from all`
and .htaccess file in /application/views/site folder : `Allow from all

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^login/?$    login.php    [NC,L]`

Answer (score 0):

This `action="#"` looks very strange. I think you should change this with `action='/site/login'`. You don't need use `base_url()` as commented above. Related path should be enough.